# Android CountDownTimer skipping interval of 1 ms

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

At first lets have a look in the logcat

```
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 0
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 2
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 3
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 5
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 6
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 7
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 13
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 15
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 16
E/StopWatchService: onTick: 17
```

See when I'm starting countDownTimer with the interval of 1 ms, according to the logcat 2,3 is printed but **4 is missing**. Similarly, 5,6,7 is printed but **8, 9, 10, 11, 12 are missing**. Why?

Now see my code.

```
mCountDownSeek = new CountDownTimer(max, 1) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                   
                    long progress = max-l;
                    Log.e(TAG, "onTick: "+ progress ); //LOGCAT

                    Intent intentABC = new Intent(Constant.ACTION_UPDATE_SEEKBAR);
                    intentABC.putExtra("progress", progress);
                    intentABC.putExtra("max", max);
                    sendBroadcast(intentABC);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                   
                }
            }.start();
```

I want a 1 ms delay or interval only. But it's skipping. How do I update my progressbar or seekbar after 1ms interval? Please answer experienced people. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Progress Bar Implementation,
Now the countdown will run for 5 mins with 1ms differences, Hope this will help you. Working solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private ObjectAnimator objectAnimator ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        // for smooth animation
        objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progressStatus);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(500);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000 /** TIMER REQUIRED FOR **/,100 /** TIME DIFFERENCES **/) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               progressStatus++;
               progressBar.setProgress((int) progressStatus*100 / (5000/1000) );
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
               // do your function of work
               progressStatus = 0;
               progressBar.setProgress(100);
            }
      };

      // call this in you on click
      countDownTimer.start();
      objectAnimator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I think you didn't understand. Im trying to set progress while the countdown timer is running.

Comment: Please check now, I have updated the code. @SubhojitHalder

Comment: But in this case progression of the bar would not be smooth enough. So I need is I need 1ms delay for smoothness while progress happens.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to make smooth progress like aftereffect animation? :) or how do I get a 1ms delay in Android for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Added Object Animator to make it smooth. @SubhojitHalder

Comment: TRY THIS METHOD GUYS
public static void smoothProgressAnimation(ProgressBar pb, int progressTo, long anim_duration)
    {
        //TODO : HOW TO SET MAX VALUE IN YOUR PROGRESS BAR?
        //TODO : pb.setMax(yourMaxValue * 100);
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pb, "progress", pb.getProgress(), progressTo * 100);
        animation.setDuration(anim_duration);
        animation.setAutoCancel( true);
        animation.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();
    }